# SQL Server (T-SQL) BAIv2 Banking File Importing Nightmare

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, import, banking

I would like to know if anyone has a good solution for importing BAIv2 banking files into SQL Server. First of all the files have "continuation records" which have to be considered along with the parent records. Also, T-SQL doesn't have a pleasant way of parsing comma-separated strings. Finally, one hierarchy in the file has a varying number of elements so that makes direct pasting into a table difficult because the columns would not line up.

This is the file from hell. If anyone has any insights into how to import and parse BAIv2 banking files I would be most appreciative.

Thank you,

Comment: I don't know anything about that file format, but I would recommend looking into `SSIS`.

Comment: If you have to do line by line processing, using a language other than SQL is preferable because string handling will be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best off handling this with a dedicated application server and a real (general-purpose) programming language.  T-SQL is ill-suited for this task.

When that's not an option, you can use C# for a [SQL CLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) stored procedure to parse the files.  I did something similar for banking flat-files when I didn't have the option of an application server.

Comment: So you would recommend avoiding T-SQL for this task? It doesn't have a native comma-separated string handling function so we came up with a set-returning function which returns a table with every row being a different element in the comma-separated string. Can't really see a good way to use that function though.

Comment: If T-SQL is the only tool in your toolbox, then you have to use it.  But, I'd recommend taking a trip to the proverbial hardware store and finding a better tool.

Comment: We have both T-SQL and C# available. We try to use only T-SQL but I don't think the language is going to cut it here.